# Polynomial time algorithm for determining if there exists an ordering of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, order-theory

Given n subsets of cardinality k of a set $S=\{1,2,...,m\}$. Is there a polynomial time algorithm to determine if there exists an ordering of subsets $s_1,...,s_n$ such that $|s_i\backslash\bigcup_{j<i}s_j|=1$ for $i=2,...,n$?

Note: In my ongoing research, $k=4$ and $m=n+3$.

Comment: Since the output will have length $n$, I assume you mean a run time bounded by a polynomial in $n$ (rather than $\log n$). Assuming this (which you could clarify), would a brute-force branch-and-check be polynomial time?